How to replicate the RuntimeDefault seccompProfile in Kubernetes to run in Docker?
I’m just curious, when developing an application on a local machine using Docker,
How can I ensure the Docker seccomp runtime profile matches what I have defined in the Kubernetes cluster?
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          securityContext:
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault

If there is a suggested Docker command to run with the seccompProfile definition, it would be appreciated.
